# Find the pedal equation of the curve $y^2=4a(x+a)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the pedal equation of the curve $y^2 = 4a(x+a)$

My Attempt:
Given curve is
$$y^2 = 4a(x+a)$$
$$y = \sqrt {4a(x+a)}$$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t $x$
$$y^{'} = \frac {1}{2\sqrt {4a(x+a)}} \cdot 4a$$

The equation of tangent to the curve at point $(x,y)$ is
$$Y - y = \frac {2a}{\sqrt {4a(x+a)}} \cdot (X - x)$$
$$\sqrt {4a(x+a)} Y - y\sqrt {4a(x+a)} = 2aX - 2ax$$
$$2aX - \sqrt {4a(x+a)}.Y + (y\sqrt {4a(x+a)} -2ax) = 0$$
Let $p$ be the length of perpendicular drawn from $(0,0)$ to this tangent so
$$p = \frac {y\sqrt {4a(x+a)} - 2ax}{\sqrt {4a^2 + 4a(x+a)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Pedal equation of $\gamma:y^2=4a(x+a)$ wrt origin $O(0,0)$ is $p^2=|a|r$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the distance of $P\in\gamma$ from the origin $0$ and $r$ is the distance from $O$ to the tangent to $\gamma$ passing through $P$.

Derivative $y'$ can be found by implicit differentiation
$$2yy'=4a\to y'=\frac{2a}{y}$$
The equation of the tangent is
$$Y-y=\frac{2a}{y}(X-x)$$
$$yY-y^2=2aX-2ax\to 2aX-yY+y^2-2ax=0$$
the distance from the origin $(0,0)$ is
$$p=\frac{y^2-2ax}{\sqrt{4a^2+y^2}}$$
while the distance of the generic point of $\gamma$ from the origin is
$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
From the equation of $\gamma:y^2=4ax+4a^2$, substitute in the equation of $p$
$$p=\frac{4ax+4a^2-2ax}{\sqrt{4a^2+4ax+4a^2}}\to p=\frac{2ax+4a^2}{\sqrt{4ax+8a^2}}\to p=\sqrt{ax+2a^2}$$
and finally
$$p^2=ax+2a^2\to x=\frac{p^2-2a^2}{a}$$
Now substitute in $r$
$$r=\sqrt{x^2+4ax+4a^2}\to r=\sqrt{(x+2a)^2}\to r^2=(x+2a)^2$$
Now plug $x$ in the equation of $r^2$
$$r^2=\left(\frac{p^2-2a^2}{a}+2a\right)^2\to r^2=\frac{p^4}{a^2}\to p^4=a^2r^2$$
The requested equation is $p^2=|a|r$.